# MS Access: Command button to save as a report as PDF

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, save

I try to create a code for a button in Access that opens the Save as dialog box to save a report with the predefined file name with a filter to PDF file type in which the user can manually select the desired folder.

I also used below code for a different button to save it as Excel file type, which works, but I don't get it to work for PDF.

Can you guys help me. Thanks.

```
Private Sub PrintButton_Click()

CurrentTime = Format(Now(), "DD_MM_YYYY hh:mm")

cmdlgOpenFile.filename = "Stock overview " & MonthMFiling & " " & YearMFiling & " " & CurrentTime & ".pdf"
cmdlgOpenFile.Filter = "PDF Files (*.pdf)|*.pdf"
cmdlgOpenFile.FilterIndex = clngFilterIndexAll
cmdlgOpenFile.DialogTitle = "Save Report As"
'this is where the dialog opens
cmdlgOpenFile.ShowSave

'returns your full file name.
filename = cmdlgOpenFile.filename

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code gets the filename. To output a report to PDF use this command:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "ReportName", acFormatPDF, filename
```

Replace "ReportName" with the name of the report you are using.

DOC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.DoCmd.OutputTo